# How to remove the tilte "category:category name"?

Tags: categories

I created a category "TEST" and added it to the main menu in header. Whenever I click on it, it takes me to the page with recent posts marked under the category. But at the top of the page it shows Category : Test" . Can I remove this?  I mean at least the "Category"?

Also, the page is not full width and I can't change that

http://www.xukia.in/category/test/

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the according template file in the [template hierarchy for the category archive](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display), which would be, in this order, either one of those:

1. category-{slug}.php
2. category-{id}.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

There you can get rid of the »Category:« part. To define the width of your content change the CSS accordingly.